# Generic and casting java rules

Tags: java, generics

i have read some generic restrictions

when it comes to casting, it said that we cannot use cast with parameterized types

could anyone explain in what situation we are allowed to cast Object data type to its subclass since generic performs the cast automatically if necessary?

suppose i have the following code:

`T[] arrayVar =(T[]) new Object[1]`// it causes a compiler warning but still okay

why should i use cast in this situation? doesnt it say that in generic, cast will be done automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `T` is not defined as `<T extends NotObject>`, then

```
T[] arrayVar =(T[]) new Object[1]// it causes a compiler warning but still okay
```

post erasure is

```
Object[] arrayVar = (Object[]) new Object[1];
```

which has a redundant unchecked cast.

This is not type-safe.

Consider what happens when you do

```
f(arrayVar)
```

where

```
void f(Object[] out) { out[0] = "A string"; }
```

If that can happen when `String` is not a subclass of `T` then you have a type-safety violation.

---

To solve this problem you can try and create an array of a more specific type.
If you can take a parameter of type

```
Class<T> clazz
```

then you can create your array thus

```
T[] varArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 1);
```

which is more type-safe because trying to do

```
out[0] = "";
```

on a `Number[]` for example will result in an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime.

It isn't perfectly (dynamically) type-safe, because `T` might be a type like `List<String>` and you can still put a `List<Number>` in a `List[]` without an `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: could you explain me more, in what situations i should use cast or when there is no need to use cast?

Comment: @Edi, you need a cast when, pre-erasure, the created value is less-specific than the generic receiver type.  When, post-erasure, the two types are the same, you need to use other mechanisms to ensure type-safety.  You can use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation to tell the compiler that you're preserving type safety some other way, but use it sparingly.